# Windows 10 Task Manager shows CPU load wrong

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I noticed this last year on someone elses PC and now that I have upgraded to Windows 10 I see it on mine too: Task Manager showing wrong CPU load procentage. See screenshot:

[image]

There is Process Explorer for comparison. At that time I was running 7-zip builtin benchmark with 6 threads. So the CPU load should be 6/8= 75% plus some bit from background tasks.

So PE is showing 80% which seems correct and TM is showing 96% which is way off.

In some cases it it the opposite: all cores are running at 100%, but TM shows less, like 80%.

Is it some known Windows 10 bug? Should I just use PE and forget TM?

---

More details:

First, showing that 7-zip is running 6 threads and the CPU load is 75% (by 7-zip and a few percents more by other background tasks).

[image]

And here the same thing, but also showing the Task Manager CPU load page:

[image]

It is obvious that Task Manager shows wrong total CPU usage by a margin of 15%.

Comment: "Is it some known Windows 10 bug?" - No;  Even Process Explorer's graph shows a high usage spike.  I suspect Task Manager CPU usage is calculated differently than Process Explorer's CPU usage.

Comment: Find out with PE what is using the CPU. (1) CPU should run <5% more than 95% of the time. So see what is using CPU. (2) TM on Windows 10 will show very high CPU when it first starts and then go right down. I have had Windows 10 for over 5 years now and there is no Windows 10 bug that uses CPU

Comment: @John CPU is used by 7-zip. I'll add more screenshots to make thing clear.

Comment: That seems strange. 7-Zip should only use CPU when zipping or unzipping files, not at idle. Check for other things. I have 3 machines running here (Windows 10, Kali and Ubuntu) on one host, email, browsers and other things and CPU is under 5%

Comment: @John 7-zip _is_ running. I started it. On purpose.

Comment: Stop 7-Zip and check your CPU load say 1 minute after stopping it

Comment: Please read what this question is about.

Comment: Good one @DavidBalažic .  I am curious myself why this is happening.

Comment: The meaning of CPU usage is complicated with a variable speed CPU, as is the case here. Windows 10 Task Manager increases the displayed usage value when turbo boost is active. This is documented but not all the details. There is logic in this but not all will agree. I don't know if Process Explorer does this but I suspect not. Process Explorer calculates process CPU usage with cycle counting while Windows 7 Task Manager used the older time based accounting. I don't know if this was changed for Windows 10. This can produce different numbers.

Comment: I did read carefully. CPU should run near zero most of the time and you need to figure out (Process Explorer) what is chewing up CPU. If not 7-Zip then what?

Comment: @LMiller7 Interesting. Can you link to the  documentation you mentioned?